# How to get JSON Web Token value for JWT use in ID propagation

Tags: json, oauth, jwt, salesforce, token

I am trying to figure out how to get a second level value from an ID token for JWT. I know I can get the first value using jwt:zoneinfo for example would return "America/New_York".  But how do I get the role under custom_attributes or the country under address? ANy help would be highly appreciated please.

```
{
  "sub": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/xxxxxxxxx",
  "zoneinfo": "America/New_York",
  "email_verified": true,
  "address": {
    "country": "US"
  },
  "iss": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "locale": "en_CA",
  "custom_attributes": {
    "role": "ADMIN"
  },
  "phone_number": null,
  "exp": 1627314099,
  "iat": 1627313799
}
```

Comment: it depends on the JSON parser and the environment that you're trying to use it it, perhaps you could specify those

Comment: the environment I am getting this from is Salesforce and I am trying to use it in a custom environment. The environment is currently reading in the other values using jwt:sub, jwt:zoneinfo etc.

Comment: what parser and programming language?